# intellij idea keeps telling me to point JAVA_HOME to jdk rather than jre

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I downgrade my version of java from 1.8 to 1.7. This is my environment variable in my .profile

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/dan/dev/jdk1.7.0_79
JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
M2_HOME=/home/dan/dev/build-tools/maven/3.2.1
ANT_HOME=/home/dan/dev/build-tools/ant/1.9.4
DAN_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
```

PATH=$PATH:$DAN_PATH
I already tried log out log in.

Comment: I think u mean Windows system environment variables?

Comment: Nope. Im using linux

Answer (score 1):

**Maven configuration of JRE:**
[image]

**Project Java SDK settings:**
[image]

When the change does not help I would try to reimport All Maven Project, restart GUI and finally create project again (just remove .idea folder and all *.iml files).